# Symfony: How to get all services and their respective classes

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

What I'm trying to achieve is the following: Some of the services in my application carry a special annotation. Later, during the build process, a special command should find all files with that annotation.

My approach is to first load all bundles:

```
$container = $this->getContainer();

foreach ($container->getParameter('kernel.bundles') as $alias => $namespace)
    $bundle = $container->get('kernel')->getBundle($alias);
```

I’m stuck at this point. How do I get the `$bundle` instance to tell me its services?

Note: I'd also be happy with a solution that is not bundle-specific, i.e. one that loads all service definitions available. The [`ContainerBuilder`](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.html) has got a `getDefinitions` which looks promising, although I don’t know how to access it from a command.

I need to get a list with the service IDs and their classes – especially the classes, because those are the ones I need to load into the annotation reader.

Obviously, I don’t want to parse `services.yml` myself, and I’d also like to avoid loading an instance of each service from `$container->getServiceIds()`.

(Btw, [*tagged* services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html) won’t help; I need annotations. And I want to detect annotated services automatically, because tagging them would require an additional step, which is unnecessary and error-prone.)

Comment: You may have to rethink your approach.  You can look in the cache directory to see what information the container has available to it.  You won't find bundle information.  In fact, it is entirely possible to define services outside of bundles completely.  Maybe tagged services is what you are looking for? http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html

Comment: Thanks for suggesting tagged services, but they are not what I'm looking for. I've updated the question with a clarification w.r.t. tagged services.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A compiler pass will still do. But instead of finding tagged services you get all definitions. This has the advantages of working with the definitions, instead of instantiating every service.

Of course you need to create a manager class, which accepts holds all class names to use it later in your command.

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class RegisterClassNamesPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->has('app.class_names_manager')) {
            return;
        }

        $manager = $container->findDefinition(
            'app.class_names_manager'
        );

        foreach ($container->getDefinitions() as $id => $definition) {
            $class = $container->getParameterBag()->resolveValue($def->getClass());

            $definition->addMethodCall(
                'addClassName',
                array($id, $class)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes … that would be the way to get to the `ContainerBuilder`, nice. I still think I’ll stick with the `getServiceIds` approach for now, because fiddling with compilation passes and storing the results in some intermediate service seems to be a bit over the top for my scenario. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Your way is instantiating every service, which may is a heavy task. And you have to do it every time, while a compiler pass is only executed once.

Comment: Ok, after giving this some thought, this might indeed be a suitable approach. Still not 100% sure, but let's try and see how far we get.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I’ve solved this for now with the less elegant approach of loading all services through `getServiceIds`:

```
$container = $this->getContainer();

foreach ($container->getServiceIds() as $id)
{
    $service = $container->get($id, $container::IGNORE_ON_INVALID_REFERENCE);
    if (!$service) continue;

    $class = get_class($service);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: You must have a super important use case.  Going through and instancing every last service seems a bit over the top.  There is a cache/dev/Container.xml file that has the info you need.  Might be quicker to read it.

Comment: The command runs only once, on build time. So I think it's ok to go through all services. (And this isn't even the most intensive part.)